# How macOS will verify my software is Notarized or not?

Tags: kernel, macos-mojave, osx-gatekeeper, notarize

As per apple document ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow "Staple the Ticket to Your Distribution" ) I have to stapled my software DMG and when User runs dmg , gatekeeper will verify it online or It will find stapled ticket in case of Internet is disconnected.

My Query is :
I have notarized my software successfully but did not staple it. And when I tried to Install my software very first time on the macOS 10.14.5 with no internet connection, my software installed successfully. But if Gatekeeper does not find stapled ticket software should not installed.
why gatekeeper does not validate ticket in this scenario ?
How macOS system validate Notarized dmg when user first time runs any downloaded dmg?
Is there any gatekeeper logs available to cross check notarization status?